# What do we mean when we say that two particles are 'correlated'?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, entanglement-entropy

I recently read about an experiment involving correlated particles. The article didn't mention what it is was but stated that it was similar to entangled particles. So if anyone could provide a simple explanation or a link to the same, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which experiment?

Comment: https://futurism.com/?p=113786

Comment: for quantum correlation see https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.00806. The paper  is in arxiv. https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.03323 I am not good on qubits; I tend to think that when entropy decreases, the system is not isolated ;but could not get that concept fast reading through the publication.